# Is my equation too complex for matlab to integrate?

Tags: matlab, integral

I have a code that needs to evaluate the arc length equation below:

```
syms x

a = 10; b = 10; c = 10; d = 10;

fun = 4*a*x^3+3*b*x^2+2*c*x+d

int((1+(fun)^2)^.5)
```

but all that returns is below:

```
ans = int(((40*x^3 + 30*x^2 + 20*x + 10)^2 + 1)^(1/2), x)
```

Why wont matlab evaluate this integral? I added a line under to check if it would evaulate int(x) and it returned the desired result.

Comment: WolframAlpha [can't integrate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+[%28%281%2B%284*a*x^3%2B3*b*x^2%2B2*c*x%2Bd%29^2%29^.5%29]) it either

Comment: Not all functions can be integrated analytically. Can you not use a numerical approximation?

Comment: You might be better of trying numerical integration. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/integration.html)

Comment: It looks like an [elliptical integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). Those can't be expressed with elementary functions, in general

Comment: When I try to solve it numerically, it returns an error stating it cannot evaluate X = 1/10 (or some number) and x must be symbolic. I posted the error in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems involving square roots of functions may be tricky to intgrate. I am not sure whether the integral exists or not, but it if you look up the integral of a second order polynomial you will see that this one is already quite a mess. What you would have, would you expand the function inside the square root, would be a ninth order polynomial. If this integral actually would exist it may be too complex to calculate.

Anyway, if you think about it, would anyone really become any wiser by finding the analytical solution of this? If that is not the case a numerical solution should be sufficient.

**EDIT**

As [thewaywewalk said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486227/is-my-equation-too-complex-for-matlab-to-integrate#comment37904098_24486892), a general rule to calculate these kinds of integrals would be valuable, but to know the primitive function to the particular integral would probably be overkill (if a solution could be found).

Instead define the function as an anonymous function

```
fun = @(x) sqrt((4*a*x.^3+3*b*x.^2+2*c*x+d).^2+1);
```

and use `integral` to evaluate the function between some range, eg

```
integral(fun,0,100);
```

for evaluating the function in the closed interval [0,100].

Comment: A lot of people would become a lot wiser if they could integrate these kind of integrals. It's a major problem in field theory ;)

Comment: I agree with you, it does not matter if I know the analytical solution to this but it is imperitive that I know the numerical solution to this evaluated from say 0 to 100. When I run the int(fun,x1,x2) code it returns:

int(((- (3377699720527821*z^3)/1267650600228229401496703205376 + (4644337115725789*z^2)/633847351602688 + 2*z + 87490099089/225179985248)^2 + 1)^(1/2), z == -8749099087/225179948..-3248603388706911/1125899906842624)
 
Error using sym/int (line 123)
Cannot integrate with respect to 'z == -3811553342128227/562949953421312'. The
integration variable must be a symbolic variable.

Comment: I am unsure as to why it is assinging a value to Z when above in the code I assigned it a sym variable (and it works for the first order integrals)

Comment: @thewaywewalk I do not question the usefulness to know the integral for square root functions. Sorry if that was how it sounded. I rather meant that even if it was possible to find the solution to this function, the particular answer would be to long to be of any use. So do not worry I do not ignore that the usefulness to have a general rule for these kind of functions :)

Comment: Sorry if I do not follow, I am new to using handles. I definte fun = @(x) sqrt(blah) and then call the integral command int(fun,0,100)?

Comment: Ok I have extended my edit, and it is as you think. However, do not use `int`. Use `integral` instead.

Comment: That code seems to work. However, it is giving me a value wayyyyyy off of what I estimate it should be. I guess that is a problem for me to tackle though! Thanks alot you really helped out!

Comment: Well `4*10*100^3 = 4e7` so I would guess that you cannot have a too small value here.